# Android back button press doesn't trigger keys.onreleased qml

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am creating a program in Qt5.3 and Qtquick2.1. I am trying to capture back button press on android in my code using Keys.onReleased. But that event is not getting triggered. Also I have set the item focus to true. But still no success. Here is the code sample

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Rectangle
{
    id: main2
    focus: true
    width: Screen.Width
    height: Screen.Height
    Keys.enabled: true
    Keys.priority: Keys.BeforeItem

    property string load_page: ""
    signal deskConnected()

    Loader{
        id: pageloader
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "qrc:/qml/resources/Firstpage.qml"
    }

    onDeskConnected: {
         pageloader.item.onDeskConnected()
    }

    function loadPatwin(){
        pageloader.source = "qrc:/qml/resources/Secondpage.qml";
    }

    Keys.onReleased: {
        console.log("back");
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back) {
            event.accepted=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here loadPatwin is the function which gets called on pressing a button which is defined in some other qml. And loads a new qml. But after that when I am pressing the back button on android, the app gets closed and it doesn't print even "back" in the logs. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is not working I have also tried everything, let me know if you have any hint

Comment: JNI_OnLoad
got it.. The problem comes up when we load the main.qml from main.cpp using QApplicationengine. Instead of that use QQuickview to load the main.qml file.

Comment: Not in my case, as I am using QQuickView to load main.qml something as well is missing in my app I guess

Comment: Where are you handling the back button event?? in qml or cpp??

Comment: In qml, in the component that I am pushing from stack view

Answer (score 17):

In qt quick (Qt5.1 and later) the `ApplicationWindow` and `Window`, both have a `closing` signal that is emitted when the user touches the back button in android.
You can simply implement an onClosing handler and set the close parameter to false. Here is how to do it:

```
onClosing: {
    close.accepted = false
}
```

By this handler you can easily manage the back button of android device. It does not need any extra permission. For example suppose you have a StackView to manage the GUI. You can write these lines of code, Then your application behaves as like as a native android app:

```
onClosing: {
        if(stack.depth > 1){
            close.accepted = false
            stack.pop();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for some time.

Comment: It is saying "Invalid property name onClosing" when I am using Qt 5.7 and QtQuick.Window 2.2...

Comment: Actually it seemed to run fine with your onClosing solution even though the programming interface marked it as an error... very strange.

Comment: @ChrisFlesher the onClosing event is going to happen in the ApplicationWindow or Window object which should be the parent component of your main.qml

Comment: What I had to do was move the close.accepted = false statement to before the if statement to prevent the back button from closing the app if the stack is at the bottom. Great solution!

Comment: This is only a workaround. `closing` is fired on every platform when the window should close, i.e. also when you press "x" in the title bar on Windows, Linux or macOS. The event should really be handled by `Keys`, but it needs to be installed on `Window::contentItem`. See my answer below for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67357598/922647

Answer (score 5):

It works for me by adding "forceActiveFocus()" after the item has completed loading.

In your example I would put it at the beginning. Like this:

```
Rectangle
{
    id: main2
    focus: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        main2.forceActiveFocus()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just stumbled upon this problem myself, but the proposed solution of handling the `closing` signal of `Window` or `ApplicationWindows` is more of a workaround than a solution. While it might work fine for Android, any cross-platform application will then employ "back"-button handling when you *actually want to close the window* (e.g. press the the "x" button on the window title bar)

To do this correctly, we have to keep in mind how key event handling in QtQuick happens: The item with `activeFocus` gets the event first. If it doesn't handle the event, it is propagated to it's `parent` item. This goes on until it reaches the root item. Here's the crux: `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` are the outermost object, but *they're not `Item`-based!* The root `Item` is actually `Window::contentItem`. This is where you need to install a `Keys` handler to receive all non-handled key events, including *Back*
button presses. Unfortunately, attached properties don't work for read-only object-typed properties, so we have to do this imperatively in `onCompleted`:

```js
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Connect to `released` signal and dispatch to `back()`
        contentItem.Keys.released.connect(function(event) {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back) {
                event.accepted = true
                window.back()
            }
        })
    }

    function back() {
        // Back button handling goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly on-point. Kudos for finding a real solution instead of a hacky one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is a good example, but I used to create my own GuiApplication class subclassing from QGuiApplication

```
#ifndef GUIAPPLICATION_H
#define GUIAPPLICATION_H

#include <QGuiApplication>

class GuiApplication : public QGuiApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
#ifdef Q_QDOC
    explicit GuiApplication(int &argc, char **argv);
#else
    explicit GuiApplication(int &argc, char **argv, int = ApplicationFlags);
#endif

    bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event);
signals:
    void back();

};

#endif // GUIAPPLICATION_H
```

This is for cpp codes

```
#include "guiapplication.h"
#include <QDebug>

GuiApplication::GuiApplication(int &argc, char **argv, int) :
    QGuiApplication(argc, argv)
{
}

bool GuiApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)
{
// to intercept android's back button
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Close) {
        emit back();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return QGuiApplication::notify(receiver,event);
    }
#else
        return QGuiApplication::notify(receiver,event);
#endif
}
```

For main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "guiapplication.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    GuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext *rootContext = engine.rootContext();
    rootContext->setContextProperty("GUI", &app);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

and finally for main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow

    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Connections {
        target: GUI
        onBack: console.log("back")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In QML === is boolean comparison

So instead of (event.key === Qt.Key_Back)

You should use (event.key == Qt.Key_Back) {